# Is it reliable to scale gitlab ECS service on single EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

we are doing a POC of Gitlab installation using AWS ECS. We created single EC2 instance and over that instance we are trying to scale the service by running multiple tasks on the same instance.

anyone have similar setup to give me some insight ?

Thanks

I tried scaling service on single ec2 but I'm seeing 422 and 500 errors in application logs.

Comment: Can you give a bit more conext, gitlab server? gitlab runner? what docker image are you using. If you are running more than one instance of gitlab how are you managing the ports for communication etc